# OAuth Plugin Produces Error With Yahoo

Tags: plugins, oauth

I've recently installed the OAuth plugin in my Wordpress site. For the most part, it seems to work as expected. Except when trying to login with Yahoo when it produces this error:

Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string in /home/content/36/9835836/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OpenID/LightOpenID.php on line 87

Line 87 begins this if statement:

```
if(($host_end = strpos($this->trustRoot, '/', 8)) !== false) {
            $this->trustRoot = substr($this->trustRoot, 0, $host_end);
        }
```

I will gladly provide any other information that would help to diagnose or fix this problem. Not that Yahoo is super important, but I'd like to give people options; so any help would be appreciated.